# How to solve async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously error in WebApi 2?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

```
public async override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Access Exception using context.Exception;
        Logger.Error(context.Exception.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        const string errorMessage = "An unexpected error occured";
        var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            new
            {
                Message = errorMessage
            });

        response.Headers.Add("X-Error", errorMessage);
        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);
    }
```

I am using above code for global exception handling in Web Api 2. Above code return following warning message. How to solve this?

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread

Comment: Have you tried adding await?

Comment: If there is nothing in the method that requires await then remove async from the method definition.

Comment: Show the complete error handler.

Comment: Where to add await in the above code?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any asynchronous work to do, then don't use `async`:

```
public override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // Access Exception using context.Exception;
  Logger.Error(context.Exception.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
  ...
  context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: It's only available as of .NET 4.6

Comment: @Zbigniew: Then you can use `return Task.FromResult(0);`. What version of .NET are you on?

Comment: I'm not OP. It's a side note that's worth including in your post.